# How can I make my discord bot mention someone without the ID in py?

Tags: python

I tried this but it can only answer in a specific person

message.author == client.user:
return

if message.content.startswith('slap <@!479915823897640972>'):
await message.channel.send( "{0.author.mention} slapped <@!479915823897640972>".format(message))

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using commands.
If you do, it would be something like this:

```
@commands.command() # This can be whatever you bot variable is
async def slap(self, ctx, user): # You can change the name to whatever
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} slapped {user}") # The only issue is that the user can be anything, from a number to a word, and not always a mention
```